# implement splitview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to implement the splitView native to the iOS in Android. In Android we can use the Fragment class. I am only wondering if anyone has a few tutorial samples I could reference as I am completely new to this.

Really appreciated.

Comment: Start by reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Comment: Lukas, thanks. I have been through this article and I am only wondering if anyone has come across full length tutorials with source code preferably..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was researching myself and saw this question while searching..

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2448-how-to-use-the-fragment-class-in-the-android-honeycomb-sdk-preview/

there was another.. in the android.developer area but it was far more simple..